# Linux benchmarking tools

Tags: linux, benchmarking

I've been asked to evaluate a new vendor's computing system and management has requested that I do NOT use any of our existing software to evaluate the platform (believe it or not, they have some valid reasons).

Anyways, I've started trying to read up on meaningful benchmark programs for server-grade computers but haven't been all that impressed.  I'm trying to demonstrate raw computing power and memory I/O throughput.

Any suggestions on meaningful tests that I should run? -- I will have access to both the existing system and the system to evaluate for all of these tests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up using the following sites to arrive at some somewhat meaningful benchmarks:

- [Linux Benchmarking HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Benchmarking-HOWTO.html)
- [SPEC](http://www.spec.org/) ([as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368472/linux-benchmarks#368874) by [matli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23896/matli))
- [Linux Benchmark Suite Homepage](http://lbs.sourceforge.net/)
- [LMBench](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/)
- [SELinux Benchmarks](http://www.nsa.gov/selinux/papers/freenix01/node13.html)

Answer (score 11):

[Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com) has a benchmark suite for Linux. Maybe it is sufficent for you.

Answer (score 4):

I like UnixBenchmark - http://code.google.com/p/byte-unixbench/. It's a well rounded test.

Answer (score 3):

[SPEC](http://www.spec.org/) is a fairly standardized and well recognized set of benchmarks. They are not free, but not very expensive. There are also a lot of published benchmark results for various servers on their web site.

Comment: It looks like SPEC is mostly for Xwindowing systems and as such wouldn't be very applicable to a non-windowing server implementation.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are obviously missing something. There are several different SPEC suites. The most well-known, SPEC CPU, is definitely not related to graphics. Actually, the only SPEC suite that appears targeted at graphics is "Graphics/Workstations".

Answer (score 2):

A lot of linux "benchmarks" ive seen demonstrate things such as encoding with LAME.  I dont know if that example holds any water for a "server-grade" test

Comment: this is rubbish, there are plenty of io,database benchmarking tools around. you've not looked hard enough.

Comment: markr - reread my reponse, i said "a lot of quote-unquote benchmarks ive seen...", not "this is what i found by googling for an answer so i can get my rep up"

Answer (score 2):

It's not FLOSS, but http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/ is pretty good :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Transaction Processing Council for ideas. They may have a result for your machines already.

Unfortunately you need to be a member to get hold of the software which is proced up to tier 1 hardware vendor levels.